# How to refer a local file for Azure emotion api

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to refer a local jpg file for using in Azure Emotion API.
To do this, I refer my file through "file:///" like below.

```
body = "{'url': 'file:///Users/jonghkim/dev_jhk/Research/Crowdfunding/Face_Analysis/me.jpg'}"
```

But the response says "Invalid image URL." How could I fix it?

{"error":{"code":"InvalidUrl","message":"Invalid image URL."}}

Whole code looks like below.

```
########### Python 2.7 #############
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers. Replace the placeholder key below with your subscription key.
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '***********************',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
})

# Replace the example URL below with the URL of the image you want to analyze.
body = "{'url': 'file:///Users/jonghkim/dev_jhk/Research/Crowdfunding/Face_Analysis/me.jpg'}"

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. The true reason was two fold. At first, when we refer local file, we should use 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' in a header.

The second problem is that the image should satisfy the condition of Azure (learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/cognitive-services/emotion/fa‌​q).

Full code is here:

```
########### Python 2.7 #############
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers. Replace the placeholder key below with your subscription key.
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '**************************',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
})

# Replace the example URL below with the URL of the image you want to analyze.
body = open('test.jpg','rb').read()

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the emotion API within Cognitive Services - just take a look at the URI. This code is not being executed locally. It's a service. Being run somewhere else.

So, when the service gets the URL (via `url` in the body), it then needs to reach out to that resource, which is impossible to do if the resource is on your computer. And `file://` is going to be an invalid scheme because the service won't be reading from its own file system.

You'll need to have your resource in an accessible place (e.g. a public or SAS-signed blob, an image link from a website, etc).

Comment: I could send my local file by changing header as below;headers = {
    # Request headers. Replace the placeholder key below with your subscription key.
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '***************************',
} also I could access my file through "///~~~" not the "//~~~".

Comment: I think the problem was that Azure supports only JPEG, PNG, GIF(the first frame), BMP. not the jpg file. refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/cognitive-services/emotion/faq

Comment: You are correct, in that using `application/octet-stream` you can upload an image payload for analysis. But that means you should not include a `url` body element, since that is specifically for online content, coupled with `application/json` content type - you would just include the image content. And jpg should work fine.